# Default location for the raw HTML file used by a Joomla Template?

Tags: html, templates, joomla, location, default

I am currently using a JA Droid Template (http://www.joomlart.com/joomla/templates/ja-droid) but I don't know where the html file is that controls the homepage. I have tried accessing it through admin, but there are a lot of installed mods that won't let me do that.

I was wondering how I could access this file via my FTP program? The normal root for a template is templates/(template name)/index.php. Unfortunately that root only leads me to a short php file that shows this:

```
<?php
if (class_exists('T3Template')) {
$tmpl = T3Template::getInstance($this);
$tmpl->render();
return;
} else {
//Need to install or enable JAT3 Plugin
echo JText::_('Missing jat3 framework plugin');
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no file that controls the home page. All Joomla templates basically work the same way. Index.php in the template usually defines the various positions that can be used for content, but none of the content should be in that file. In this case, your template uses a framework to build the page, but it still works the same way. The home page is controlled by the home menu item and the various modules that are assigned to that menu item. The menu item determines which component the page will be built around and the menu assignments are determined within each module in the module manager.

Answer (score 3):

I installed a Jat3 template and needed to modify the line in the footer and took me a while but i found it here...

Plugins/system/jat3/jat3/dase-theme/default/blocks

you'll find all you need...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the whole code is taken from the plugin. You should look in the plugins directory. The directory name should be "jat3" or something like that...

Answer (score 0):

Good Day,

All templates are managed through the template manager.

1. Login to the control panal http://example.com/administrator
2. Extensions > Template Manager (in the main menu)
3. Select the Template you wish to edit
4. Select Edit HTML to edit the main template (or edit CSS)

And that's it. If you wish to know where those files are actually stored so you can edit them with your favorite FTP editor (rather than through Joomla), login to your home directory with FTP (or SFTP), select the folder "templates" then the template folder name, then edit index.php (to edit your html), or select folder CSS, and edit template.css (usually the default name), to edit your css.

Hope this helps!

Cheers,
Christopher